# A triangle of Gaussian primes

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry

Let $Z_{1}, Z_{2}$ and $Z_{3}$ be 3 Gaussian primes.

Is there any triangle whose vertices are $Z_{1}, Z_{2}$ and $Z_{3}$ and its centroid $(Z_{4} = (Z_{1} + Z_{2} + Z_{3})/3)$  is a Gaussian prime?

$Z_{1}, Z_{2}$ and $Z_{3}$ satisfy the triangle inequality that, if we set $a = |Z_{2} - Z_{3}|, b = |Z_{3} - Z_{1}|$ and $c = |Z_{1} - Z_{2}|$, then $a + b > c, b + c > a$ and $c + a > b$.

Comment: Equivalently, you are asking for Gaussian primes $a,b,c,d$ such that $a+b+c=3d$. (I assume you want $a,b,c,d$ distinct. Do you also want them not collinear—for example, not all real?) It is possible to prove that there are many such examples. In general, given any single linear equation (with integer coefficients) in *$\ge3$ variables*, current technology can find infinitely many solutions where all the variables are prime (unless there's an obvious modular obstruction that would force, for example, an odd number to equal an even number). These methods should work for Gaussian primes as well.

Comment: @ Greg Martin Thanks! I added the triangle condition.

Comment: @SeiichiKirikami What do you mean by "satisfy the triangle inequality"?  The triangle inequality holds for any three points :).

Comment: @Erick Wong I added 3 inequalities as above.

Comment: @SeiichiKirikami Ahh, so a simpler way of describing the same thing is that the three points are not collinear (these inequalities will always hold in the non-strict sense, so the strictness only implies non-collinearity).